# Show default content for a fragment in Intellij UI Designer

Tags: android, android-layout, intellij-idea, android-fragments, android-listfragment

Is there any way to set some type of placeholder for xml elements in an Android fragment which are normally loaded at runtime so that I can preview the layout? For example, I'm using a custom fragment which extends the Android ListFragment, and I need to have some placeholder list items in order to design the layout using the IntelliJ UI Designer.

Answer (score 0):

Place an image in the drawable folder for whichever resolutions you would like to test. The images can be created quickly on a site such as [Placehold.it](http://placehold.it/).For a listView you can just reference the id of the image multiple times.